# go to php link using html?

Tags: html

```html
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="div-category">
    <div class="input-box button">
      <a href="logintest.php">
        <input type="submit" name="" value="click to login">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this method not working, i can't reach the php link

Comment: Why would you have an `<input>` inside of a link?  That makes no sense.  Just put text inside the link.  Or a text element, such as a `<span>`.  (Though even that shouldn't be necessary really, any styling you want can be applied to the `<a>`.)

Comment: thank you but i should put an input since i have its own style in css, can the text hold the same style in this case ?

Comment: Both a link and a button can be styled however you want them.  But you should choose whether you want to use a link **or** a button.  Not both.

Comment: Even aside from that, what's "not working" about this?  When I click on the button I'm navigated to `logintest.php`.

Comment: yes i am using a button rather than a link, that is my main problem i should pick one

Comment: It’s worth putting code through a validator. In this case I get “ The element input must not appear as a descendant of the a element.” and see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're already using bootstraps, I suggest using the built-in [button classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/buttons/). You can always overwrite the CSS to customize the buttons more, but this is a great starting place for you.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-lg-6">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="logintest.php">click to login</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you guys I got the answer:

```css
.clickme {
  -moz-appearance: button;
  -ms-appearance: button;
  -o-appearance: button;
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  appearance: button;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.2em 0.4em;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #564cda 0%, #d3bac6 100%);
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.clickme:hover {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #53b9e9 0%, #0f3fdd 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="div-category">
    <div class="input-box button">
      <a class="clickme" href="logintest.php">Click to Login</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```